# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'questionRecord') - questionRecord is a prisma model representation

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma

I am trying to record a question on a prisma model. The model is defined as following:

```
model QuestionRecord {
 id                    String                  @id
 institution           String
 title                 String
 imagepath             String
 alternatives          String
 subject               String
 topic                 String
 year                  Int
 StudentQuestionRecord StudentQuestionRecord[]
}
```

To make any record on that model, I use the following class and its typing:

```
import { randomUUID } from "crypto";

export interface QuestionEntity {
   id: string,
   year: number,
   title: string,
   topic: string,
   subject: string,
   imagepath: string,
   institution: string,
   alternatives: string,
};

export class Question {
   public _id: string;
   public props: Omit<QuestionEntity, 'id'>;


   constructor(props: Omit<QuestionEntity, 'id'>, id?: string) {
       
       this._id = id ?? randomUUID();
       this.props = props;
   }

   public get id() {
       return this._id;
   }

   public get title() {
       return this.props.title;
   }

   public set title(newQuestionTitle) {
       this.props.title = newQuestionTitle;
   }

   public get topic() {
       return this.props.topic;
   }

   public set topic(newQuestionTopic) {
       this.props.topic = newQuestionTopic;
   }

   public get subject() {
       return this.props.subject;
   }

   public set subject(newQuestionSubject) {
       this.props.subject = newQuestionSubject;
   }

   public get year() {
       return this.props.year;
   }

   public set year(newYear) {
       this.props.year = newYear
   }

   public get institution() {
       return this.props.institution;
   }

   public set institution(newInstitution) {
       this.props.institution = newInstitution;
   }

   public get alternatives() {
       return this.props.alternatives;
   }

   public set alternatives(newAlternatives) {
       this.props.alternatives = newAlternatives;
   }

   public get imagepath() {
       return this.props.imagepath;
   }

   public set imagepath(newImage) {
       this.props.imagepath = newImage;
   }
}
```

Finally, I have this route that allows one to request the creation of a question:

```
@Post('create/question')
 async createQuestionView(@Body() body: CreateQuestionBody) {
   const {id, year, title, topic, subject, imagepath, institution, alternatives } = body;

   const { question } = await this.createQuestion.execute({
     id,
     year,
     title,
     topic, 
     subject,
     imagepath,
     institution,
     alternatives 
   });
   return {question: QuestionViewModel.toHTTP(question)};
 }
```

By the way, here's other snippets that may be helpful in the troubleshooting, as suggested by Shea. Here is how execute method was written:

```
interface CreateQuestionResponse {
   question: Question;
}

@Injectable()
export class CreateQuestion {
   constructor(private questionRepository: QuestionRepository) {}

   async execute(request: QuestionEntity): Promise<CreateQuestionResponse> {
       const {
           institution, subject, topic, title,
           year, alternatives, imagepath
       } = request;

       const question = new Question({
           alternatives, 
           institution, 
           imagepath,
           subject, 
           topic, 
           title,
           year, 
   });

       await this.questionRepository.create(question)

       return { question };
   }
}
```

Here is how `PrismaQuestionRepository` was written:

```
export class PrismaQuestionRepository implements QuestionRepository {
   constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}

   async create(question: QuestionEntity): Promise<void> {
       const raw = PrismaQuestionMappper.toPrisma(question);

       await this.prisma.questionRecord.create({
           data: raw,
       })
   }
   async findQuestionById(questionId: string): Promise<QuestionEntity | null> {
       const question = await this.prisma.questionRecord.findUnique({
           where: {
               id: questionId,
           }
       });

       if (!question) return null;

       return PrismaQuestionMappper.toDomain(question);
   }
   async findQuestionsByYear(year: number): Promise<QuestionEntity[] | null> {
       const questions = await this.prisma.questionRecord.findMany({
           where: {
               year: year,
           }
       });

       if (!questions) return null;

       return questions.map(PrismaQuestionMappper.toDomain);
   }
   async findQuestionsByTitle(title: string): Promise<QuestionEntity[] | null> {
       const questions = await this.prisma.questionRecord.findMany({
           where: {
               title: title,
           }
       });

       if (!questions) return null;

       return questions.map(PrismaQuestionMappper.toDomain);
   }
   async findQuestionsByTopic(topic: string): Promise<QuestionEntity[] | null> {
       const questions = await this.prisma.questionRecord.findMany({
           where: {
               topic: topic,
           }
       });

       if (!questions) return null;

       return questions.map(PrismaQuestionMappper.toDomain);
   }
   async findQuestionsBySubject(subject: string): Promise<QuestionEntity[] | null> {
       const questions = await this.prisma.questionRecord.findMany({
           where: {
               subject: subject,
           }
       });

       if (!questions) return null;

       return questions.map(PrismaQuestionMappper.toDomain);
   }
   async findQuestionsByInstitution(institution: string): Promise<QuestionEntity[] | null> {
       const questions = await this.prisma.questionRecord.findMany({
           where: {
               institution: institution,
           }
       });

       if (!questions) return null;

       return questions.map(PrismaQuestionMappper.toDomain);
   }
   async findQuestionsBySubjectAndTopic(subject: string, topic: string): Promise<QuestionEntity[] | null> {
       const questions = await this.prisma.questionRecord.findMany({
           where: {
               subject: subject,
               topic: topic,
           }
       });

       if (!questions) return null;

       return questions.map(PrismaQuestionMappper.toDomain);
   }   
}
```

Here is how mapper was written:

```
export class PrismaQuestionMappper {
   static toPrisma(question: QuestionEntity) {
       return {
           id: question.id,
           year: question.year,
           title: question.title,
           topic: question.topic,
           subject: question.subject,
           imagepath: question.imagepath,
           institution: question.institution,
           alternatives: question.alternatives,
       };
   };

   static toDomain(raw: QuestionEntity) {
       return new Question({
           year: raw.year,
           title: raw.title,
           topic: raw.topic,
           subject: raw.subject,
           imagepath: raw.imagepath,
           institution: raw.institution,
           alternatives: raw.alternatives,
       });
   };
};
```

My application runs quite well, until I try to record a question. Whenever I try to, passing in all necessary fields, I got this error:

```
[Nest] 13784  - 03/01/2023, 09:00:47   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'questionRecord')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'questionRecord')
   at PrismaQuestionRepository.create (/home/famialiaaes/Documents/Estudos/NestJs/student-microservice/student/src/infra/database/prisma/repositories/prisma.question.repository.ts:12:27)
   at CreateQuestion.execute (/home/famialiaaes/Documents/Estudos/NestJs/student-microservice/student/src/app/use-cases/question/create.question.ts:29:39)
   at AppController.createQuestionView (/home/famialiaaes/Documents/Estudos/NestJs/student-microservice/student/src/infra/http/controllers/app.controller.ts:52:52)
   at /home/famialiaaes/Documents/Estudos/NestJs/student-microservice/student/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:38:29
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
   at /home/famialiaaes/Documents/Estudos/NestJs/student-microservice/student/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
   at /home/famialiaaes/Documents/Estudos/NestJs/student-microservice/student/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17
```

I know that this error occurs when a supposed property of an undefined thing is called. So I re-read all my code and refactor it in some snippets, as well I pocked around with it in order to see what can have been evaluated as undefined but could not dilute the problem yet. I hope someone can help me out with, pointing out some nuance that failed to see. Thanks in advance!

Issue solved: as `PrismaQuestionRepository` is a class that is part of the nestjs module, on top of it I should have put an @Injectable decorator, what I haven't since now. After doing this, the problem disappeared.

Comment: Your error refers to an issue with `PrismaQuestionRepository.create` but this function's definition is not provided in your question. Please include it so we can more meaningfully help you.

Comment: I included `PrismaQuestionRepository` and a little more. Now I believe things are a bit more conceptualised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `this.prisma` is undefined when you attempt to run `this.prisma.questionRecord.create`. When you instantiate `PrismaQuestionRepository`, you have to pass in `prisma` (looking at its constructor.) Make sure you are properly instantiating `PrismaQuestionRepository`, which seems to be the root of your error.

Comment: Thank you so much for narrowing down the scope of the issue. You made me analyse more carefully the file where I declared the `PrismaQuestionRepository` so I noticed that have not put the @Injectable decorator atop the that same class. After putting it and re-running the application, this problem vanished. I really appreciated your time and effort helping me!